# Terminal use gdb to debug .cpp files, (gdb)p command

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb

When I use gdb to debug, I just want to use '(gdb)p x' to print the value of x, but the result is very complicated. Terminal command like this:

`(gdb) p word`

Output:

```
$2 = {<std::__1::__basic_string_common<true>> = {<No data fields>}, static __short_mask = 1,
  static __long_mask = 1,
  __r_ = {<std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__rep, 0, false>> = {__value_ = {{__l = {__cap_ = 1970239750,
            __size_ = 0, __data_ = 0x0}, __s = {{__size_ = 6 '\006', __lx = 6 '\006'},
            __data_ = "you", '\000' <repeats 19 times>}, __r = {__words = {1970239750, 0,
              0}}}}}, <std::__1::__compressed_pair_elem<std::__1::allocator<char>, 1, true>> = {<std::__1::allocator<char>> = {<No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>},
  static npos = 18446744073709551615}
```

What I really want is `__data_ = "you"` this segment only.

**How can I get a simple result like this:**

`$2 = "you"`

Can someone help me? Very appreciate that.

Comment: Did you try support pages?  Like this for instance https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I get a simple result like this:

That's what GDB pretty-printers are for.

It looks like you are using `libc++` (and probably Clang).

From `libc++` [documentation](https://libcxx.llvm.org/UsingLibcxx.html#gdb-pretty-printers-for-libc):

GDB does not support pretty-printing of libc++ symbols by default. However, libc++ does provide pretty-printers itself. Those can be used as:

```
$ gdb -ex "source <libcxx>/utils/gdb/libcxx/printers.py" \
      -ex "python register_libcxx_printer_loader()" \
      <args>
```

---

You can put the `source <libcxx>/utils/gdb/libcxx/printers.py` and the `python register_libcxx_printer_loader()` commands into your `~/.gdbinit`, and then things will just work™.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It's not a big problem indeed.

Comment: Hi, I try to follow your solution to solve this problem, but I don't know what `source <libcxx>utils/gdb/libcxx/printers.py` means exactly. Should I just add `source <libcxx>utils/gdb/libcxx/printers.py` to my ~/.gdbinit profile?

Comment: `vim ~/.gdbinit` 
this profile only has one line **set startup-with-shell off**

Comment: I don't know where **printers.py** is.